# Rails version stuck at 2.3.5 how to update to 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi there thanks for looking into this.

after a clean install of Linux ubuntu 10.10 i tried to re-install rails.

after doing `sudo gem install rails`, I can see I am returned version 3.2.3 of rails

But after generating a new project i couldn't find my gemfile so i tried ruby -v which returns 2.3.4 wich is odd since I know I got the latest.

Also when trying sudo gem update --system I get an error because I might override system files. any solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to manage your ruby sets -- as well as defining gemsets for each project that will allow you to make sure each project has just the gems it needs.

Here's a link to the rvm installation instructions (they should work with ubuntu):

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Here's some info on basic use of gemsets with rvm:

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/

Also, when using rails 3+, you should make a practice of typing `bundle exec rails -v` -- that way you'll use the gems defined for the project you're in.

Can you try typing `bundle exec rails -v` and letting us know what you see?

Comment: Thank, you very much I have chosen to redo the installation completely since I did not do it in the right order